# How can I set routing conditions based on the Doctrine Entity specified by one of the parameters?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

So I've got two Doctrine entities, let's call them Box and Item. A box contains multiple items. I want the URLs for viewing an item to look like this:

```
/box/{box_id}/item/{item_id}
```

Obviously I want to show a 404 error message if the item (specified by the `item_id`) does not belong to the box specified by the `box_id` in the URL. I could do this by adding a check in every action in the controllers, but then I'd have to write the same code many times.

I'm looking for a way to specify the requirement without having to scatter if statements (or function calls) throughout all my functions. I've read about the condition-field (yaml) that can be used to specify more complex conditions, but I'm not quite sure how I'd get a reference to a doctrine repository from there.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I could do this by adding a check in every action in the controllers, but then I'd have to write the same code many times.

No, this is what we use functions for. So that only *one* line is duplicated between every action that needs them, and the function holds reusable code.

All you need to do is write a function which takes an `item_id` and a `box_id`, and returns `true` or `false` depending on relation.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how functions work. I was trying to find out if there was a way to avoid doing that. I've ended up creating a ParameterConverter that accepts a `condition` field, so I can just write `@ParamConverter("item", options={"id": "item_id", "condition": "entity.getBox().getId() == box_id"})` which IMHO looks nicer than adding function calls everywhere.